# How to use scripting elements within apache tiles in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, apache-tiles

I'm trying to add apache tiles to spring boot.

Whenever I try to put in real jsp code with tags like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<tiles:insertTemplate template="/default.jsp" flush="true">
    <% out.println(new java.util.Date()); %>
</tiles:insertTemplate>
```

This throws this error.

```
Scripting elements ( &lt;%!, &lt;jsp:declaration, &lt;%=, &lt;jsp:expression, &lt;%, &lt;jsp:scriptlet ) are disallowed here.
```

I have "scripting-invalid" set to "false" for .jsp and I don't know how to solve this.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well based on the exception, it seems it is not allowed to have `<%  %>` inside tags

Could you try the following options:

Option 1:

```
<% request.setAttribute("content", new java.util.Date()); %>
<tiles:insertTemplate template="/default.jsp" flush="true">
    ${content}
</tiles:insertTemplate>
```

---

Option 2:

```
<c:set var="content">
           <% out.println(new java.util.Date()); %>
</c:set>

<tiles:insertTemplate template="/default.jsp" flush="true">
    ${content}
</tiles:insertTemplate>
```

Please do confirm if this worked for you,